# Redirect 301 relative to url in php

Tags: php, redirect, seo

I am moving to a new domain name and I need to redirect all incoming links to the new domain name. All the pages are on both websites.

(ex.: www.oldsite.com/services.php and www.exemple.com/services.php are both actives and identical.)

I would like to know if my code is SEO-friendly without messing with the .htaccess file.

```
<?php
$referer = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$domain = "www.exemple.ca";
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if(strpos($referer,$domain) === false) {
    header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
    header( "Status: 301 Moved Permanently" );
    header( "Location: http://www.exemple.ca$uri" );
    exit(0);
} ?>
```

Comment: it would be much easier to do that via htaccess (in two lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points:

- You probably want `HTTP_HOST` (the hostname requested), not `SERVER_NAME`.
- Assuming you aren't using any subdomains, there's no need to use `strpos`, I would just compare the two hostnames and redirect if they aren't equal
- You only need one 301 header
- htaccess would be considerably faster than using PHP for this, particularly if you have a htaccess file already

With that in mind I'd probably rewrite your code as:

```
<?php
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$domain = "www.exemple.com";
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if($referer != $domain) {
    header( "Location: http://www.exemple.ca$uri" true, 301);
    exit(0);
} ?>
```

You may also only want to do this for GET requests.

The htaccess verison (assuming mod_rewrite is enabled) would be:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(^www.exemple.ca)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.exemple.ca/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank's a bunch for these tips

Answer (score 0):

`301` is about as SEO friendly as it gets. It indicates to spiders that the page has permanently moved.